# why on IE my overlay is not showed when i add it to the dom before a page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

On ie if i do something like this:

```
var aOverlay = $('<div>');
aOverlay.addClass("modal_overlay");    
aOverlay.prependTo(aAppendTo);
window.location.reload(false);
```

then the overlay is not show at all. but if i replace

```
window.location.reload(false);`
```

with

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(false);},300)
```

then it works. Why ?

Comment: Why are you reloading the page to begin with?

Comment: Reloading a page is like erasing a whiteboard. It does not show since their is no need to, the page is exiting so why update.

Comment: I'm very confused as to why you are reloading the page after prepending something to it. and the only thing having "false" inside of window.location.reload does it use the cache rather than re-downloading data from the server.

Comment: `$('<div>')` is wrong. You want `$('div')` which will return all the div's on the page.  The overlay doesn't show because you are immediately reloading the page, erasing the current contents. It probably works in your setTimeout version because you made a typo that prevents it from running. Right-click the page, chose "Inspect Element", click the Console tab, and see if there are any error messages.

Comment: @TomRobinson - No, I think the OP is using `$('<div>')` to *create* a div... (What's the typo in the `setTimeout()` version? Looks fine to me.)

Comment: @nnnnn you're right, I had not used that jquery construct before.

Comment: reload it's just a sample i take. what i want to say is why the div is not showed imediatly after the aOverlay.prependTo(aAppendTo); how to to (instead of delaying the code that run after) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a browser-specific quirk if changes before the reload get displayed or not. IE is trying to optimize page rendering by delaying page updates until all page updating has stopped.

***Q:*** If the page is about to be discarded, should recent page updates be rendered?

***A1:*** No! A new page is coming, so simply display that. *(IE)*

***A2:*** Yes! The updates are what the user is going to be staring at while the new page is fetched from the server. *(Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari)*

The solution, as you found with `setTimeout(...,300)`, is to delay for a short interval before reloading the page. This forces page updates to be rendered, so that they can be visible during the delay interval.

The delay can be shorter than 300ms. In fact, it can be 0 or omitted entirely. According to W3C standards, the interval is actually a minimum of 4ms.

This sample renders the overlay as a translucent gray layer over the entire page:

```
    <?php sleep(1); /* simulate typical server delay */ ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
    <style>
    .gray_overlay { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%; 
       padding:0; margin: 0; z-index:999; background-color:#202020; opacity:0.4 }
    button { display:block; margin:20px }
    </style></head><body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    This is some text. Server takes 1s to respond.
    <button onclick="v1()">Version 1: Show overlay then reload instantly.</button>
    <button onclick="v2()">Version 2: Show overlay then reload in 0ms.</button>
    <script>
    var aAppendTo = $('body');
    var aOverlay = $('<div>');
    aOverlay.addClass("gray_overlay");    
    function v1() {
        aOverlay.prependTo(aAppendTo);
        window.location.reload();
    }
    function v2() {
        aOverlay.prependTo(aAppendTo);
        setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();});
    }
    </script>
    </body></html>
```

[image]